# Update Access database through Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to update table in Access through this code but it shows error message "User define type not define". How to solve this problem? 
    enter code here

```
Sub UpdateClick()
   Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
   Dim myRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
   Dim strConn As String
Dim s As String
Set s = "C:\Users\PC2\Documents\Database2.accdb"

   strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 Data Source=s"
Set strConn = New ADODB.Connection

   Set myRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

   With myRecordset
      .Open "Select * from PersonInformation", strConn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
      .Fields("ID").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
      .Fields("FName").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value
      .Fields("LName").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value
      .Fields("Address").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").Value
      .Fields("Age").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2").Value
      .Update
      .Close
   End With

   Set myRecordset = Nothing
   Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you include the microsoft access object library in references? just curious.

Comment: Well when i add library It shows message "Name conflict with existing module,project,object library"

Comment: Try changing the line `strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 Data Source=s"` to `strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 Data Source=" & s`.  Also remove the `Set` statement from where you define the value of `s`.

Answer (score 0):

After my comment I noticed you had more wrong than just the connection.
Adapt your code to the example below - sites such as https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/ will show you which string to use for your version of Access.

```
Sub FillArrayAccess()

    Dim oConn As Object
    Dim myRecordset As Object
    Dim sConn As String
    Dim s As String

    s = "C:\Users\PC2\Documents\Database2.accdb"

    'Your connection string will change depending on the Access version.
    sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & s
    'sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & s 'Access 2010

    Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    oConn.Open sConn

    Set myRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
    myRecordset.Open "PersonInformation", oConn, 1, 3, &H2

    With myRecordset
        .AddNew
        .Fields("ID").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
        .Fields("FName").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value
        .Fields("LName").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value
        .Fields("Address").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").Value
        .Fields("Age").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2").Value
        .Update
        .Close
    End With

    Set myRecordset = Nothing
    Set oConn = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Edit:**  Have updated code to work with original posters data.